# Why I'm getting error can't find file name in other folder then the one I gave?

Tags: c#

```
private void GetMessages()
{
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Csharp Projects\Get Messages\Sources");//Assuming Test is your Folder
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.html"); //Getting Text files

    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.Name))
        {
            string line;

            while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.Contains("msg-bullet"))
                {
                    int index = line.IndexOf("<");
                    int index1 = line.IndexOf(">");

                    string result = line.Substring(index, 4);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on the line :

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.Name))
```

> Could not find file 'D:\Csharp Projects\Get Messages\bin\Debug\Source0.html

The path from the error message `D:\Csharp Projects\Get Messages\bin\Debug` isn't the path or even a subpath from the one I provided in the source, eg `D:\Csharp Projects\Get Messages\Sources`

Why isn't the given path used ?

Comment: The path provided in your error message is the compiled executable path.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use file.FullName :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
```